# Create a Pool of JAXB Unmarshaller

Tags: spring, jaxb, pool, unmarshalling

I was looking around to find a way to improve JAXB Unmarshalling performances processing huge sets of files and found the following advice:

*"If you really care about the performance, and/or your application is going to read a lot of small documents, then creating Unmarshaller could be relatively an expensive operation. In that case, consider pooling Unmarshaller objects"*

Googling the web to find an example of this didn't return anything, so I thought it may be of interest to put my implementation here using Spring 3.0 and Apache Commons Pool.

`UnmarshallerFactory.java`

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import org.apache.commons.pool.KeyedPoolableObjectFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * Pool of JAXB Unmarshallers.
 * 
 */
@Component
public class UnmarshallerFactory implements KeyedPoolableObjectFactory {
    // Map of JAXB Contexts
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private final static Map<Object, JAXBContext> JAXB_CONTEXT_MAP = new HashMap<Object, JAXBContext>();

    @Override
    public void activateObject(final Object arg0, final Object arg1) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void passivateObject(final Object arg0, final Object arg1) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public final void destroyObject(final Object key, final Object object) throws Exception {
    }

    /**
     * Create a new instance of Unmarshaller if none exists for the specified
     * key.
     * 
     * @param unmarshallerKey
     *            : Class used to create an instance of Unmarshaller
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public final Object makeObject(final Object unmarshallerKey) {
        if (unmarshallerKey instanceof Class) {
            Class clazz = (Class) unmarshallerKey;
            // Retrieve or create a JACBContext for this key
            JAXBContext jc = JAXB_CONTEXT_MAP.get(unmarshallerKey);
            if (jc == null) {
                try {
                    jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
                    // JAXB Context is threadsafe, it can be reused, so let's store it for later
                    JAXB_CONTEXT_MAP.put(unmarshallerKey, jc);
                } catch (JAXBException e) {
                    // Deal with that error here
                    return null;
                }
            }
            try {
                return jc.createUnmarshaller();
            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                // Deal with that error here
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean validateObject(final Object key, final Object object) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

`UnmarshallerPool.java`

```
import org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class UnmarshallerPool extends GenericKeyedObjectPool {
    @Autowired
    public UnmarshallerPool(final UnmarshallerFactory unmarshallerFactory) {
    // Make usage of the factory created above
    super(unmarshallerFactory);
            // You'd better set the properties from a file here
    this.setMaxIdle(4);
    this.setMaxActive(5);
    this.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
    this.setTestOnBorrow(false);
    this.setMaxWait(1000);
    }

    public UnmarshallerPool(UnmarshallerFactory objFactory,
        GenericKeyedObjectPool.Config config) {
        super(objFactory, config);
    }

    @Override
    public Object borrowObject(Object key) throws Exception {
        return super.borrowObject(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void returnObject(Object key, Object obj) throws Exception {
        super.returnObject(key, obj);
    }
}
```

And in your class that require a JAXB Unmarshaller:

```
    // Autowiring of the Pool
    @Resource(name = "unmarshallerPool")
    private UnmarshallerPool unmarshallerPool;

    public void myMethod() {
        Unmarshaller u = null;
        try {
            // Borrow an Unmarshaller from the pool
            u = (Unmarshaller) this.unmarshallerPool.borrowObject(MyJAXBClass.class);
            MyJAXBClass myJAXBObject = (MyJAXBClass) u.unmarshal(url);
            // Do whatever
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Deal with that error
        } finally {
            try {
                // Return the Unmarshaller to the pool
                this.unmarshallerPool.returnObject(MyJAXBClass.class, u);
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        }
    }
```

This example is naive as it uses only one Class to create the JAXBContext and uses the same Class instance as the Key for the Keyed Pool. This can be improved by passing an Array of Classes as parameter rather than only one Class.

Hope this can help.

Comment: Uhm.... this isn't a question....

Comment: Well I dunno where how can I create a topic that is not a question.

Comment: Hi hut, I think this is valuable and SO does allow for "answering own questions", maybe as an advice you could restructure your post in the form of a question and providing your implementation as an "answer" which you can then accept.

Comment: This is a bit old, but looks like a very good approach. http://axixmiqui.wordpress.com/2009/09/01/spring-injecting-jaxb-unmarshaller/

Answer (score 1):

The creation of unmarshallers is intended to be light.  I would recommend doing some profiling before developing a pooling strategy.

Comment: As I said this is all based on the advice found <a href="http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Performance_and_thread_safety.html">here</a> telling that the instantiation of multiple Unmarshallers can be an expensive operation. Even without profiling, I can tell you that my app runs much faster with Unmarshaller pooling.

Comment: The creation of JXAB unmarshallers is NOT LIGHT, whatever the intention is.